# jquery/2.2.0 - TypeError: $.initElementData is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running an A/B test and have written some jQuery which works in the preview panel - but when i push it live - I don't see the changes and I'm seeing an error:

> TypeError: $.initElementData is not a function
>
> ...his,c);return}}c.unshift("Generic
>   Events");this.genericHandler.apply(this,c)}})
>
> jquery.... > eval (line 1, col 9180) TypeError: $.ui is undefined
>
> $.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {

I've tried googling this - and it appears to speak to old version of jQuery - but I'm using the latest?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please see my code below:

```
</head>
<script>
jQuery.fn.extend({
    live: function (event, callback) {
       if (this.selector) {            
            jQuery(document).on(event, this.selector, callback);
        }
    }
});
  //Online Only
  //Available Online    Not Available in Stores
 $('div.result-sold').each(function() {

 if($(this).find('li:contains("Available Online")').length>0 && 
    $(this).find('li:contains("Available Online")').next('li:contains("Not Available In Stores")').length>0){


        $(this).find('li:contains(Not Available In Stores)').remove();    
      $(this).find('li:contains("Available Online")').text('Online Only');

       }  
  }); 


  //In Stores Only
  //Not Available Online    Available in Stores

   $('div.result-sold').each(function() {

 if($(this).find('li:contains("Not Available Online")').length>0 && 
    $(this).find('li:contains("Not Available Online")').next('li:contains("Available In Stores")').length>0){


        $(this).find('li:contains(Not Available Online)').remove();    
      $(this).find('li:contains("Available In Stores")').text('In Stores Only');

       }  
  }); 




 /* Temp sold out online :: Not available in stores */
  $('div.result-sold').each(function() {

  if($(this).find('li:contains("Temporarily Sold Out Online")').length>0 || 
    $(this).find('li:contains("Temporarily Sold Out Online")').next().text()==="Available In Stores") {     

      $(this).find('li:contains("Available In Stores")').remove(); 
      $(this).find('li:contains("Not Available In Stores")').remove(); 

     }  
}); 


   /* sold out online :: available in stores */
  $('div.result-sold').each(function() {

  if($(this).find('li:contains("Sold Out Online")').length>0 || 
    $(this).find('li:contains("Sold Out Online")').next().text()==="Available In Stores"){     

      $(this).find('li:contains("Available In Stores")').remove(); 


     }  
}); 


</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where is this script tag located in your page? I'm assuming it's in the head right? if it is, then it will load jQuery in it's entirety before executing your code.  It seems as if jQuery is not fully loaded before this code is executed. If you move your script to just before the body tag, do you get the same result?